# Custom Snippet, if first choice is "this" then second choice has to be "this"

Tags: code-snippets

I have a little question about custom code snippets. Is it possible to make multi choice snippets have if conditions?

So if you chose "Level" in the first choice you can only pick "uint8" in the second one. But if you on the other hand chose "Name" in the first one then you only have the choice of "LSString" in the second one and so on. But then if you pick "AllChoices" you can pick freely.
Is there some magical code I can use? So far I haven't been able to find it.

```
"Attributes": {
    "prefix": "attribute",
    "body": [
        "\<attribute id="${1|Level,Name,AllChoices|}" type="${2|uint8,LSString|}" /\>"
        ]
    }
```